# Create a SQL Server Redirect (Alias / Linked Server)

Tags: sql-server

I currently have a database on a named SQL server instance called \Mobius and database name of Mobius

We need to move the database to the default (parent) instance but don't necessarily want to update our connection strings in all our applications (initially) so that a call to \Mobius will point to having the database of the same name.

Is there a way this can be done?

Comment: Outside SQL Server, via a DNS (bind, Active Directory) server or your hosts file.

Comment: @CraigEfrein I think they are trying to keep not only the server name but the named instance available and just have the old named instance path point to the default instance.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are looking to do but as the answer notes you will only be able to have a single instance running after the change.

[Pointing all connections to the default instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11921896)

Answer (score 0):

IF Mobius is the only database being connected to be the clients (ie you don't need a database-specific redirection) AND it's only a few clients connecting AND they're using the Native Client... you can log onto each machine and set an alias in SQL Configuration Manager.

Instructions from MS here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms190445.aspx

You specify a server/instance and the new server/instance all outgoing connections will be redirected to. So you'd specify server\mobius and a replacement of server, and it would send them there whenever they tried to connect.

Aliases are a little old school but still supported, however they also make for easy auditing through SMO (you can remotely gather details of who has overrides set anywhere).